# Render partial error from test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial. At the end of paragraph 5.3.1 I'm running the tests that we've programmed as part of the tutorial. For all 4 tests/views it generates the following error:

```
ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.207317345] test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.21s) ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: Missing partial layouts/_shim with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
          * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
          * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views"
          * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3690625791535586393_66697380'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3690625791535586393_66697380'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

I have a file app/views/layouts/_shim.html.erb, so that seems okay, and application.html.erb is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The test is:

```
  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
```

I don't understand what what causes the error. In the controller it just read `def about; end` and the routes `get 'static_pages/about'`

The project structure is:

- Sample_app

  - .bundle
  - .git
  - App

    - Assets

      - Images
      - Javascripts
      - Stylesheets
    - Controllers
    - Helpers
    - Mailers
    - Models
    - Views

      - layouts

        - _footer.html.erb
        - _header.html.erb
        - _shim.html.erb
        - application.html.erb
      - static_pages

        - about.html.erb
        - contact.html.erb
        - help.html.erb
        - home.html.erb
  - Bin
  - Config
  - Db
  - Lib
  - Log
  - Public
  - Spring

Comment: Missing partial layouts/_shim  u have that trouble, can u show ur project structure?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the project structure. Hope that helps. Rendering the header and footer doesn't seem to generate a problem and I don't see a difference with shim...

Comment: show me views/layouts ls -la

Comment: Does the shim show up when you view the page?

Comment: I’ve added the structure for the views directory. I’m not sure what you meant with ls la (sorry, really new to this and only familiar with Windows). When I enter app/views/layouts ls -la in the terminal it just sais “bash: app/views/layouts: Is a directory”.

Comment: Shim contains <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
  </script>
<![endif]-->   so it doesn't really have something to show.

Comment: But I now see that when I go to the page in the browser, it also gives an error message:    
Missing partial layouts/_shim with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

Comment: @Legendary wanted you to go to the terminal and do `ls -la app/views/layouts`.

Comment: try to change render to render partial: "layouts/shim"

Comment: ls -la app/views/layouts produces:    
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 17 19:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 16 21:48 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  384 Mar 17 19:16 _footer.html.erb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  367 Mar 17 19:16 _header.html.erb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  119 Mar 18 11:57 _shim.html.erb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  526 Mar 18 11:17 application.html.erb

Comment: When I change it to <%= render partial 'layouts/shim' %>  it gives the error message ` undefined method 'partial'`

Comment: <%= render partial: 'layouts/shim' %>  u forget ':'

Comment: Sorry about that. It than gives the original error message:  
Missing partial layouts/_shim with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

Comment: When I remove the render line completely from application.html.erb, the error message changes to a problem with the header rendering:  
Missing partial layouts/_header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"

Comment: rly wierd, mb it want to absolute path, somethink like render partial: '/layouts/shim'  , i try to repeat ur project now

Comment: STOP. ur folder "Views" exactly "Views" with "V"  ? it have to be "views"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mb885wnc5tz070/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-03-18%2015.25.24.png?dl=0 thats my proj structure

Comment: Sorry about the capitals, they are indeed small caps (Word turned them into capitals when I hit enter). I have uploaded the folder structure to: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wii1lba613a7cf/folderstructure.gif?dl=0

Comment: When I remove the rendering of shim as well as of header, and keep the rendering of footer (in application.html.erb), it turns out that it works and there's no error message. I don't see how shim and header differ from footer and why these two generate error messages.

Comment: try remove all code from shim and header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73248/discussion-between-legendary-and-nick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces in your file names, just rename them to:

```
_header.html.erb
_shim.html.erb
```